# Why can't I find `len(list)` in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.  I have a method that begins:

```
def foo(self, list):
    length = len(list)
```

I've called `len()` successfully in other cases, but here I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

How do I convince Python that this object passed in is a list?  What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. And I don't see why it shouldn't work. Of course your `list` parameter shadows the type `list`, but you should still be able to call `len` on it. Can you provide a minimal listing that will fail with that error?

Comment: Sorry, no time for that.  I changed the name to `lst` and it works.

Comment: -1: "Sorry, no time for that".  You cannot provide enough information for us to help?  Sorry we can't be more helpful, but without more information, we're just guessing.

Comment: No, sorry that I don't have time to fully explore this problem, now that KennyTM's solution has fixed it.  The help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `list` is the name of the list type.

Use a different name.

```
def foo(self, lst):
    length = len(lst)
```

And make sure you didn't call `foo` like this:

```
Foo.foo(list)
```

Comment: That makes no sense, and wouldn't cause the problem. A parameter or variable can have any name, even one that shadows a builtin, and it won't magically refer to the builtin instead of the actual value.

Comment: Perhaps it made more sense after the edit, but I think KennyTM is saying also be sure not to call the method passing in something called "list" either (unless it is also overwritten to mean something else).

I think most of us here would agree that using the same name as a builtin is a surefire way to run into problems and confusion when you're learning a language. Coders should avoid this, as a best practice, unless they truly intend to override/shadow a builtin (which is rare).

Answer (score 5):

you're shadowing built-in. The value that you're passing to `foo` method is not a list object, but rather a `list` type, that doesn't have any length.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're calling `type()` on `list` which is a type itself. Don't use the name `list` for your lists because it is a already a built-in type. use `L` or `mylist` or whatever and it should work.